# How to stop BasicArrowButton from expanding to take the entire toolbar?

Tags: java, swing, layout, preferredsize, jtoolbar

I am creating an window with a `JToolBar` containing two buttons.  One is a regular `JButton` and the other is a `BasicArrowButton` (`javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicArrowButton`).  Without doing any additional configuration, the `JButton` does not expand in the toolbar, but the `BasicArrowButton` expands to occupy the complete toolbar.

I have tried to configure it to fit in a small 16x16 square by setting its maximum and preferred size to 16x16.  But that doesn't work.  Also tried using setSize() without success.  Can anyone tell me where the problem could be?

I have also tried to use a horizontal glue (I am using WindowBuilder with Eclipse) to the right of the `BasicArrowButton`.  That didn't work either.

I am using JDK1.7.0_07.

```
public class ToolbarTest {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ToolbarTest window = new ToolbarTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ToolbarTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        frame.getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
        toolBar.add(btnEdit);

        //------------------------------------------------------------
        JButton btnUp = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.NORTH);
        btnUp.setSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
        btnUp.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(16, 16));
        toolBar.add(btnUp);
        //------------------------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  It is likely you need to override the `getMaximumSize()` to instead return `getPreferredSize()`.

Comment: It is not recommended to use components from the Look and Feel packages in this manner

Comment: You shouldn't set sizes. Instead try using a layout manager: toolBar.setLayout(...);

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks.  I wasn't aware of it.  I am reading about it now. I would now rather use a button with an arrow icon.

Comment: Try to add an empty JPanel or JLabel() as the third component

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `JToolBar` uses `DefaultToolBarLayout`, a subclass of `BoxLayout`. You can substitute your own using `setLayout()`. `FlowLayout` may be a suitable choice:

```
JToolBar bar = new JToolBar("Edit Menu");
bar.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another example why you shouldn't call any of the [setXXSize methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657) :-)

As @trashgod already mentioned, the default LayoutManager of the JToolBar is-a BoxLayout which respects the maxSize of a component. So trying to somehow make the button return something reasonable is a step into the correct direction. Which surprisingly has no effect at all.

The reason it has no effect here is that ... BasicArrowButton returns hard-coded sizes, that is the value set via XX is simply ignored. Here's the core snippet:

```
public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
    return new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

The way out is to extend and override, f.i.:

```
JButton btnUp = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.NORTH) {

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

};
```