# why cell renders differently when text in the cell has λ characters

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I use a table with default cell renderer.
i see when i use this letter(λ) in my text, it render the whole text in the cell in different way.

[image]

I'm wondering if someone knew the reason and the solution.

Comment: It's like an issue with the font.  You'll need to make sure you're using one that is capable of displaying Unicode characters properly.  Tested using Windows and Look and Feel and it seems fine. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: See also [How to determine if 2 fonts have equivalent glyphs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683630/how-to-determine-if-2-fonts-have-equivalent-glyphs)

Comment: Thanks for your hint. It helped me to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by Intellij IDE.
I solved the problem by changing the IDE Encoding to ISO-8859-1.